# How can I make a layout like the attached image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I am trying to design a layout which contains a form and couple of items. but I found it too hard to put items in right places.
In the following image, the right frame is what I am aiming to design and the left on is what I could made.
[image]
And this is the code for the right frame:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{


    public GUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(new JLabel("Title"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panel.add(formPanel);
        TitledBorder formPanelTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("GridLayout(1,2)");
        formPanel.setBorder(formPanelTitle);

        //LEFT PANEL
        JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        TitledBorder labelsPanelTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("GridLayout(4,1)");
        labelsPanel.setBorder(labelsPanelTitle);

        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 1"));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 2"));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 3"));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 4"));

        formPanel.add(labelsPanel);

        //RIGHT PANEL
        JPanel fieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        TitledBorder fieldsPanelTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("GridLayout(4,1)");
        fieldsPanel.setBorder(fieldsPanelTitle);

        fieldsPanel.add(new JTextField("Label 1"));
        fieldsPanel.add(new JTextField("Label 2"));
        fieldsPanel.add(new JTextField("Label 3"));
        fieldsPanel.add(new JTextField("Label 4"));

        formPanel.add(fieldsPanel);

        //BOTTOM PANEL
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        TitledBorder BottomPanelTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("GridLayout(2,1)");
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BottomPanelTitle);
        panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Browse"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Label"));
        TitledBorder buttonPanelTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("FlowLayout()");
        buttonPanel.setBorder(buttonPanelTitle);
        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        JPanel secondButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        secondButtonPanel.add(new JButton("Back"));
        secondButtonPanel.add(new JButton("Next"));
        TitledBorder secondButtonPanelTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("GridLayout(1,2)");
        secondButtonPanel.setBorder(secondButtonPanelTitle);
        bottomPanel.add(secondButtonPanel);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new GUI();

    }

}
```

I am not sure if the code is really optimal, since there are a lot of inner panels and made it too complicated. Also I could not put items in the places I wanted to. Is there any suggestion or idea to make this layout look better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a `JPanel`, using `GridBagLayout` and add your labels/fields to it, this forms the "center" portion of your layout.
- Create a `JPanel` and add the `Browse` button a `JLabel` to it.  Using `GridBagConstraints#gridwidth` set to `REMAINDER`, add this to your first panel
- Create a `JPanel`, using `BorderLayout`, add the first panel to the `CENTER` position.  Add the title `Label` to the `NORTH` position, you may need to adjust it's `horizontalAlignment` property
- Create a `JPanel` using `FlowLayout`, aligned to the `RIGHT` and add your "Back" and "Next" buttons to it.  Add this to the `SOUTH` position of the previous panel.

Check out [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details